# Tower Git GUI says working directory is clean but can't switch branches - "Your working tree contains changes" error

Tags: git, working-directory

I've looked at about 10 answers to what seem to be a similar issue but I don't understand the answers in those threads sorry.

Tower states that my working directory is clean in two out of three branches - I can switch between these two branches with no issues.

But I have a third branch that I can't switch to and get the error: `Could not switch branch to “branch-name“. Your working tree contains changes that would be overwritten by checkout.`

**I suspect this might have something to do with the reason I was switching branches:**

1. I realized my `.gitignore` file wasn't working
2. This was because I had previously committed the files I was now trying to ignore (cache files)

**So I was going through a process of:**

1. updating permissions on these files
2. deleting them
3. updating the .gitignore file in each branch
4. committing

And I was doing this on each branch one by one - starting with the third branch and working my way back.

Now that this has been completed on all 3 branches, I can't switch back to the third branch.

Does the working tree in the third branch now have uncommitted changes somehow?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you have unapplied changes in stash maybe?

Comment: Thanks mate, I would have to stash files myself for that to happen right? i.e. Git doesn't stash files automatically does it? I just ran `git stash list` but nothing came up so I assume there's nothing stashed

Comment: Yeah, at least I don't think you can auto stash changes unless maybe a failed rebase happened. Also are you sure that you used git rm to delete the files? I've had that happen before where i just rm files and it won't let me switch branches.

Comment: I think that could be it. I was trying to `git rm -r directory/*` without much luck, so went to the OSX finder and deleted them! So is there a way to switch (they're just cache files) or is that branch totally buggered?

Comment: Might need to either do git add -u or git add -A and then commit or git checkout the missing files and git rm them. Not sure if just git rm on missing files will work

Comment: OK, so have ditched the Tower GUI and tried to switch in the command line and have more info: the files Git has an issue with a temp files in the branch I'm trying to switch to - as the working directory in the current branch is clean. Just not sure how I tell git to not worry about them when I can't actually switch to that branch?

Comment: You should do git clean to get rid of those files then.

Comment: Sorry dude, I'm totally confused. I googled git clean and have just ran `git clean -n -d tmp/file-name` on the 3 files without issues - but I still can't checkout the branch. Is the issue in the current branch (the one where the working directory is clean) or the branch I'm trying to switch to? If it's the branch I'm trying to switch to, how do I clean those files when I can't switch to the branch?

Comment: -n is a dry run you should do git clean -d -x -f

Comment: Thanks heaps mate but I still get the same error when I try to checkout the third branch. Just to confirm, I ran `git clean -d -x -f tmp/file-name` on each of the three files without issue before trying to switch - does that look correct?

Comment: I would run it without the filename to make sure that all the temp files and such get removed. Or if you're gung-ho about it just do git reset --hard HEAD and then git pull and then switch

Comment: Tried what you suggested but no joy. In the end I just deleted them all then checkout the branch - now I can switch between all branches. I guess git was saying the working directory was clean because the .gitignore file was setting git to ignore files in that directory?